# Can I start a new D&D Adventurers League character at a higher level?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, dnd-adventurers-league

I wanted to join an Adventurers League game at my LGS. The only game that has room is for levels 11-15.

All my previous experiences were pretty casual D&D but as I'm reading up on Adventurers League I'm a little unsure.

Can I just make a (legal) level 11 or 13 character and show up? Is that a faux pas? Is it going to cause problems for other players/GM?

(I'm going to try to contact the GM directly but I'm not sure if I can.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start by familiarising yourself with the [Adventurers League Player's Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack).

Among other useful resources, it contains a copy of the [FAQ](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv6-1.pdf), which tells you:

> *What Level Do I Start Play At?*
>   **All characters begin play at 1st level.** However, by
>   DMing and playtesting adventures, you earn
>   experience that you can apply to characters of your
>   choosing—including 1st-level characters that you
>   haven’t played yet.

Comment: Basicly, besides actualy playing a character you can level him up by giving out experience to him from DMing|playtesting games, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: I've gotten more familiar with my local community and they really do have a strong preference for enforcing this.

Answer (score 2):

### **Officially ... no**

**Unofficially it happens all the time**

If you turn up at your local game store with 1 or 2 DMs all working with 8th level characters they will usually let you join in. You may have issues porting these PCs to another table but no decent DM is going to turn away someone who is keen to play.